# How to create a CSV Reader in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

There is a [tf.TextLineReader](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#TextLineReader) and [decode_csv](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#decode_csv) in TensorFlow. But there is no CSV_Reader. I just interested to know how can I zip them in order to feed it into [tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_features](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/contrib.learn.html#read_batch_features).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about reading the CSV files with `decode_csv` and feeding them to `tf.train.shuffle_batch_join` ?

It's what `tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_features` does with it's extracted features after all: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/graph_io.py#L212

[read_batch_features](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/graph_io.py#357) is a wrapper over [tf.contrib.learn.read_keyed_batch_examples](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/graph_io.py#L90)

Comment: Actually, I'm going to modify [this source](https://github.com/dennybritz/chatbot-retrieval/blob/master/udc_inputs.py#L38-L46) to feed from my csv dataset instead of TFRecord file. So, looking for a minimum modification. Any suggestion?

Comment: try putting `tf.TextLineReader` as the `reader` argument for `read_batch_features`, and `tf.decode_csv` for the `parse_fn` argument

Comment: 'read_batch_features' doesn't accept 'parse_fn', I should call [read_batch_example](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/contrib.learn.html#read_batch_examples) function. Thank you.

Comment: links are broken. Its old version, doesn't apply to tf2.x

Comment: yeah that's a problem with all of stackoverflow

Comment: a huge fraction of the answers are for years ago